# Pandas Dataframe Remove all Rows with Letters in Certain Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe in python that I want to remove rows that contain letters in a certain column. I have tried a few things, but nothing has worked.

Input:

`A    B    C`
`0    9    1    a`
`1    8    2    b`
`2    7    cat  c`
`3    6    4    d`

I would then remove rows that contained letters in column 'B'...

Expected Output:

`A    B    C`
`0    9    1    a`
`1    8    2    b`
`3    6    4    d`

Update:
After seeing the replies, I still haven't been able to get this to work. I'm going to just place my entire code here. Maybe I'm not understanding something...

```
import pandas as pd

#takes file path from user and removes quotation marks if necessary
sysco1file = input("Input path of FS1 file: ").replace("\"","")
sysco2file = input("Input path of FS2 file: ").replace("\"","")
sysco3file = input("Input path of FS3 file: ").replace("\"","")

#tab separated files, all values string
sysco_1 = pd.read_csv(sysco1file, sep='\t', dtype=str)
sysco_2 = pd.read_csv(sysco2file, sep='\t', dtype=str)
sysco_3 = pd.read_csv(sysco3file, sep='\t', dtype=str)

#combine all rows from the 3 files into one dataframe
sysco_all = pd.concat([sysco_1,sysco_2,sysco_3])

#Also dropping nulls from CompAcctNum column
sysco_all.dropna(subset=['CompAcctNum'], inplace=True)

#ensure all values are string
sysco_all = sysco_all.astype(str)

#implemented solution from stackoverflow
#I also tried putting "sysco_all = " in front of this
sysco_all.loc[~sysco_all['CompanyNumber'].str.isalpha()]

#writing dataframe to new csv file
sysco_all.to_csv(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\testcsvfile.csv")
```

I do not get an error. However, the csv still has rows with letters in this column.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the `B` column be string type, we can use `str.contains` here:

```py
df[~df["B"].str.contains(r'^[A-Za-z]+$', regex=True)]
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this. I've edited my post to provide more details.

Answer (score 2):

here is another way to do it

```
# use isalpha to check if value is alphabetic
# use negation to pick where value is not alphabetic

df=df.loc[~df['B'].str.isalpha()]

df
```

```
    A   B   C
0   9   1   a
1   8   2   b
3   6   4   d
```

OR

```
# output the filtered result to csv, preserving the original DF
df.loc[~df['B'].str.isalpha()].to_csv('out.csv')
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this. I've edited my post to provide more details.

Comment: updated the answer, you need to assign back to the DF or perhaps a new df

Comment: @MichaelCrosby, did it worked? solution was updated

Comment: No, I never could get it to work. I ended up using a work around, but it's not something I'd feel comfortable with pushing out to others.